# Handling vacuous truths in proving elementary set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I was working on this simple problem:

> For sets $A$ and $B$, prove that $A\subset B\Leftrightarrow A\cup B=B$.

Now I know how this proof works: First suppose $A\subset B$, then take $x\in A\cup B$, and so on. What I'm concerned about is how can we handle vacuous truths(or more specifically, empty sets).

For example, let's show that if $A\cup B=B$, then $A\subset B$. We will most likely take $x\in A$. However, if $A=\varnothing$, then there is no such $x$. Another example is when we show the converse. Then, we will take $x\in A\cup B$. However, there is no such $x$ if $A\cup B$ is empty.

I know this may sound like nitpicking, but I'm not sure if I can just ignore those cases. I've seen numerous proofs here on MSE, but they seem to have no problem taking an element from a set that may be empty. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct... in principle. If $A = \emptyset$, then $\emptyset \cup B=B$ and it's done.

Comment: Having said that, if $A=B=A \cup B= \emptyset$, we have that $x \in A \cup B$ is False. Thus, $x \in A \cup B \to x \in B$ is True. An this holds also for $Y$ whatever in place of $B$. Thus, we have proved that, for $Y$ whatever: $\forall x (x \in \emptyset \to x \in Y)$.

Comment: And what does it mean: $∀x(x \in \emptyset → x \in Y)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, and formally a lot of proofs should start with: *If $A = \emptyset$, then it holds that $P$. So we assume that $A \neq \emptyset$ [..]*

However in most situations the claim follows immediately for empty sets (because of vacuous truths), so it is common practice to omit the case $A = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A=\varnothing$ then it is immediate that for every $x\in A$ we have $x\in B$.

This because no element of $A$ can be found for which this is false.

This simply because $A$ has no elements.

You might get more grip "vacuous truth" if you look at the contrapositive statement.

The statement $x\notin B\implies x\notin\varnothing$ is evidently true, and is actually the "same" statement as $x\in\varnothing\implies x\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

These proofs require a universal quantifier.

$$\forall x:p(x),$$

which can be read as $$p(x_1)\land p(x_2)\land\cdots p(x_n).$$

But in the vacuous case, the conjunction is simply

$$\text{true}.$$

Said differently, no element disproves the claim.

---

With the existential quantifier, we have a similar situation.

$$\exists x:p(x)$$

is

$$p(x_1)\lor p(x_2)\lor\cdots p(x_n),$$

which "degenerates" as

$$\text{false},$$

no element has the property.

---

You can compare to vacuous sums, which are defined as $0$, and vacuous products, $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Those cases are handled implicitly.

When we say "Let $x \in A$" we are actually saying "For all $x$ such that $x \in A$" and that includes the vacuous case.  As all conditions are true for all $x$ that don't exist any statement about the vacuous state will be true.

"For all $x$ such that $x \in A$, it holds that $x\in A\cup B$".  That is true.  If there are such $x$ that follows by definition union. ANd if there are no such $x$ the statement is true as there are no such $x$ to falsify it.

And for all $x$ it follows as all such $x \in A\cup B=B$ so for all such  $x: x\in B$. Again if there is no such $x\in A$ this vacuously follows as there are no $x$ to falsify it.

So you *aren't* ignoring anything.  You just arent *explicitly* stating these cases.

.....

Upshot:   "If $x$ does something A then $x$ does something B" means "for all $x$ such that $x$ does something A then $x$ does something B".  And that  will always be vacuously true if there are not $x$ that do something A.